# How to rspec mock ruby rails logger class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, rspec, mocking

Hi I and trying to rspec mock the following class:

```
    class Person
      def initialize(personid)
        Rails.logger.debug "Creating person with id #{personid}"
      end
    end
```

Using this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
  describe Person do
    describe "#initialize" do
      let(:rails_mock) { double("Rails").as_null_object }
      let(:logger_mock) { double("Rails.logger").as_null_object }

      it "logs a message" do
        rails_mock.stub(:logger).and_return(logger_mock)
        logger_mock.should_receive(:debug)
        Person.new "dummy"
      end
   end
end
```

and getting this message:

> RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (Double "Rails.logger").debug(any args)
>       expected: 1 time
>       received: 0 times

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd do:

```
Rails.stub_chain(:logger, :debug).and_return(logger_mock)
```

Don't forget do unstub at the end of your test:

```
Rails.unstub(:logger)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I get  `undefined method 'stub_chain' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 5):

Here is an updated answer to this using partial double:

```rb
let(:personid) { 'dummy' }

before do
  allow(Rails.logger).to receive(:debug).and_return nil
  Person.new(personid)
end

it { expect(Rails.logger).to have_received(:debug).with(a_string_matching(personid)) }
```

No need to "unstub" anything, RSpec does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The stub did not work because those stubs aren't linked to the real code. It should be like this instead:

```
require 'spec_helper'
  describe Person do
    describe "#initialize" do
      let(:logger_mock) { double("Rails.logger").as_null_object }

      it "logs a message" do
        Rails.stub(:logger).and_return(logger_mock)
        logger_mock.should_receive(:debug)
        Person.new "dummy"
      end
   end
end
```

---

For OP: if you just want to set expectation on logging, you don't need to stub the whole logger class at all. You can just do

```
Rails.logger.should_receive(:debug)
```

---

Bonus: if you just want to stub so no logging will occur, do this:

```
Rails.logger.stub(:add){ true }
```