# Testing module without Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got some Rspec tests that I'm using to test a module.  The module is used by a number of models in my Rails app.  In order to keep testing time down to a minimum, I want to avoid loading Rails when testing my module.

The problem is that there are a few methods that contain rescues and those rescues mention the Rails debugger.  When Rspec sees the capital 'r' in Rails, it has a bad time because it considers it an uninitialized constant.

I was hoping that if I wrapped up the logging info into its own method, I could avoid the problem.  Here's what I came up with.  But if I go down this road, I would need to stub either the rescue code or or the log_info method.  Is that right?  How would I do that?  And which one should I stub?

```
def download_robots_file(page)
  file = Net::HTTP.get(URI("#{page}robots.txt"))
rescue StandardError => ex
  log_info('robot_file', ex)
end
....
private

def log_info(problem, exception_issue)
  Rails.logger.debug("Couldn't download #{problem}: " + exception_issue.inspect)

end
```

Comment: Here is example of stubing Rails logger:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249815/how-to-rspec-mock-ruby-rails-logger-class

Comment: Yes, the stub().and_return() method is what I'm looking for.  Thanks.  Did you want to submit that as an answer?  I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Thanks added so that question has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to stub chain method that you want to stub.

```
Rails.stub_chain(:logger).and_return(mocked_logger_instance)
```

Un-stub in the end with:

```
Rails.unstub(:logger)
```

All credits go to mister on following link [How to rspec mock ruby rails logger class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249815/how-to-rspec-mock-ruby-rails-logger-class)